# Py installed from scoop can't find installed Python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, scoop-installer

After installing python using scoop:

```
scoop install python
```

When running `py -3 script.py`, py.exe, which is the Python Launcher for windows, can't find an installed Python.

```
py -3 script.py
No installed Python found!
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed python using scoop, there's a tip in how to fix this. It is easy to miss:

```
scoop install python
...
...
Allow applications and third-party installers to find python by running: "C:\Users\[Username]\scoop\apps\python\current\install-pep-514.reg"
```

So in order to fix it just run this from your powershell terminal:

**Replace [Username] with your real user.**

```
C:\Users\[Username]\scoop\apps\python\current\install-pep-514.reg
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use `Join-Path -Path $Env:USERPROFILE -ChildPath 'scoop\apps\python\current\install-pep-514.reg'`. That would obviate the requirement to change the username.